# Customizing biber-biblatex authoryear-ibid: multiple citations with same author

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

Following advice I got on this list (thanks!) I switched from natbib APA to natbib authoryear-ibid, which looks quite nice, but there is one major flow, which one of the authors noticed: when you have a citation with two references with the same author, the name of the author is written twice. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{bib17,
   AUTHOR = {Joyce, Terry},
   TITLE = {{The Significance of the Morphographic Principle for the Classification of Writing Systems}},
   JOURNAL = {Written Language and Literacy},
   YEAR = {2011},
   VOLUME = {14},
   PAGES = {58--81},
}

@PHDTHESIS{bib16,
   AUTHOR = {Joyce, Terry},
   TITLE = {{The Japanese Mental Lexicon: The Lexical Retrieval and Representation of Two-Kanji Compound Words from a Morphological Perspective}},
   SCHOOL = {University of Tsukuba},
   YEAR = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\bibnamedash{\mbox{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt}\space}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\begin{document}
According to \citet{bib16,bib17}, we have...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

which is suboptimal: I would expect `\citet{bib16,bib17}` to produce “Joyce (2001; 2011)” instead of “Joyce (2001) and Joyce (2011)” as if these are not the same Joyce. After all if I wanted to have “Joyce (2001) and Joyce (2011)” I would have written `\citet{bib16} and \citet{bib17}`.

What do I need to change to obtain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to 'compress' citations by the same list of authors/editors, you'll want to look into the `comp` sub-style family of the standard `biblatex` styles.

The 'comp' version of `authoryear-ibid` is `authoryear-icomp`, so you probably just want

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

You can find examples of all standard styles in https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples. In the documentation of `biblatex` 3.13 the section dealing with the standard styles (§3.3 *Standard Styles*, pp. 72-78) has handy links directly to those examples.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\bibnamedash{\mbox{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt}\space}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{bib17,
  AUTHOR  = {Joyce, Terry},
  TITLE   = {The Significance of the Morphographic Principle
             for the Classification of Writing Systems},
  JOURNAL = {Written Language and Literacy},
  YEAR    = {2011},
  VOLUME  = {14},
  PAGES   = {58--81},
}
@PHDTHESIS{bib16,
  AUTHOR = {Joyce, Terry},
  TITLE  = {The {Japanese} Mental Lexicon:
            The Lexical Retrieval and Representation of
            Two-Kanji Compound Words from a Morphological Perspective},
  SCHOOL = {University of Tsukuba},
  YEAR   = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\begin{document}
According to \textcite{bib16,bib17}, we have...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: According to Joyce (2001, 2011), we have...]

Comment: And how can I have a semicolon instead of a comma between the two dates?

Comment: OK, I found the answer: it is `\renewcommand\compcitedelim{;\space}`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @yannis `\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\multicitedelim}` (or maybe `\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}`) would be slightly nicer.

Comment: I have another question: in this style there is no comma between author name and year, which is fine. *But* when I use `this volume` instead of a year, I get the author name followed by “this volume” which is weird. Is there a way to obtain a comma whenever the year is “this volume” or “in press”? Or how should I encode these two special cases?

Comment: @yannis You can get a comma at all times with `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`. If you want one only if you have non-date `dates`, I suggest you ask a new question.